# Prime number printer function, crashes when passed large enough numbers

Tags: c, arrays, crash, c99

I've got this piece of code that would print prime numbers up to the screen.

For example, printPrimes(500000) would fill the screen with all prime number's up to the 500000th one (which is 7368787).

Problem is, passing a larger number like 600000 or 1000000 would break the program.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
typedef enum {false, true} bool;

bool isPrime(long number, long primes[], long n) {
    int divisor, index;
    for (index = 0; index < n; ++index) {
        divisor = primes[index];
        if (divisor * divisor > number) {
            return true;
        } else if (number % divisor == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void printPrimes(long n) {
    long primes[n];
    long odd, index;
    primes[0] = 2;
    odd = 1;
    index = 1;
    while (index < n) {
        odd += 2;
        if (isPrime(odd, primes, n)) {
            printf("%ld ", odd);
            primes[index] = odd;
            ++index;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here:

```
long primes[n];
```

You are overflowing the stack if `n` is large enough (the stack is quite small). Try using `malloc` instead.

```
long *primes = malloc(sizeof(*primes) * n);
```

Comment: Great. It works alright after changing that line. Thanks! I was always wondering where this site got it's name from.

Comment: Remember to `free` memory that you've `malloc`ed when you're done with it. Also, use `size_t` to represent object sizes and array indices. `long` _might_ be big enough on your platform, but might fail on other platforms (also, what're you supposed to do with -1?).